# How to prevent feature clicks through popup?

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I need a popup to be opened when clicking on the features of a vector layer. I used the [Vector Icon Example](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.11.2/examples/icon.html?q=vector%20icon) as starting point. My problem is that when a feature is covered by the popup, you can still click it ([Fiddle-Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Ld9rup3v/): click the lower point and you can click the upper one through the popup). How can prevent this behavior?

Relevant code:

```
map.on('click', function(evt) {
    var element = popup.getElement();
    $(element).popover({
    "placement": "top",
    "html": true
}); 
var popover = $(element).data("bs.popover");
var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel, function(feature, layer) {
    return feature;
});
if (feature) {
    popup.setPosition(feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates());
    popover.options.content = feature.get("name");
    $(element).popover('show');
} else {
    $(element).popover('destroy');
}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `stopEvent: true` to your `ol.Overlay` object, as such:

```
var popup = new ol.Overlay({
  element: element,
  positioning: 'bottom-center',
  stopEvent: true
});
```

See your [updated Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Ld9rup3v/2/).

Comment: That was simple, thank you! But what if I want to add options into the popup, e.g. a button with an event listener. This button also gets deactivated then, see demo: https://jsfiddle.net/Ld9rup3v/3/

Comment: Not exactly.  What I think happens is the listener on the buttons is registered first, which means is executed last.  If you register a listener when the button is created, then it will happen before the event prevention.  See an updated version here: https://jsfiddle.net/Ld9rup3v/9/.

Comment: Now it works! Thank you, Alexandre! Just a tiny blemish remains: `map.on('pointermove', function(e) { ... }` still sets the cursor to "pointer" when there's a feature under the popup.

Comment: For that one, I don't know.  I suggest you create a new thread about this.