# Mouse cursor changes over features even if they are hidden by an overlay

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openlayers-3

I'm trying to change the cursor when moved over a feature with OpenLayers 3. I'm using this code:

```
map.addInteraction(new ol.interaction.Select({
  condition : function(event) {
    return ol.events.condition.pointerMove(event);
  }
}));
```

My problem comes when the feature is hidden by a popup (created just like in the [OL3 examples](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.17.1/examples/popup.html)). When you move the mouse where the feature is, it still changes the cursor even if the feature is hidden by the popup.

Is it possible to disable the selection for features if they are not visible?

See an [example](https://jsfiddle.net/07pkLeqq/3/).

Comment: Can you check if this anwsers your question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33936795/how-to-prevent-feature-clicks-through-popup/33939477#33939477

Comment: That prevents clicking, but the cursor is still changed on mouse over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to stop the mousemove event bubbling up to the map when the mouse is over the popup

```
document.getElementById("popup").onmousemove = function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
};
```

See [edited fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ColAmes/kj3aj3m7/2/)

Comment: It works! I was looking in the OL library and didn't think of a more low level solution. Thanks!